# How to use Process Pool Executor in tornado with synchronous code?

Tags: python, tornado, blocking, process-pool

I am new to tornado and have an API that makes a blocking database call. Because of this blocking call, tornado isn't able to serve all the requests if multiple requests come at the same time.

I looked about it and found out that it could be solved using two approaches: Making the code asynchronous and/or using Process Pool Executors. My assumption here is that having multiple process pool executors is like having multiple processes on tornado to serve multiple requests. Every single example I looked at about implementing Process Pool Executor also makes the code asynchronous.

I cannot make the code asynchronous for the time being because it would require more code changes and so I was looking at simple fix using Process Pool Executors.

What I have currently

```py
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web


def blocking_call():
    import time
    time.sleep(60)
    return "Done"


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        val = blocking_call()
        self.write(val)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = tornado.web.Application([(r"/", MainHandler)])
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

What I tried

```py
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


def blocking_call():
    import time
    time.sleep(60)
    return "Done"


class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def initialize(self, executor):
        self.executor = executor

    def get(self):
        val = self.executor.submit(blocking_call)
        self.write(val)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(5)

    app = tornado.web.Application(
        [(r"/", MainHandler, dict(executor=executor))])
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

My problem with this approach is that now I am getting a `future object` instead of actual response. How do I make the `Get` request wait for `self.executor` to complete before sending back the response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `executor.submit()` returns a `concurrent.futures.Future` which is not awaitable.

I suggest you use Tornado's [`run_in_executor`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.run_in_executor) method to execute the blocking task.

```
async def get(self):
    loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()
    val = await loop.run_in_executor(self.executor, blocking_call)
    self.write(val)
```

Comment: It's giving 500 error `TypeError: object Future can't be used in 'await' expression`

Comment: @Lambda Ah, yes, I forgot that `executor.submit` returns a `concurrent.futures.Future` which is different from `asyncio.Future`. I've updated the answer.